# How to reference the key of `Record<>` in the record value

Tags: typescript

Given the following `MyKey` type

```
type MyKey = 'alpha' | 'beta' | 'charlie' | 'delta'
```

I'd love to define a `Record` type where each key must be present AND each value must be a function that returns an object with `name` property that is the same as the key.

Here's my best attempt

```
type MyRecords = Record<MyKey, () => {name: MyKey}>

const example: MyRecords = {
    'alpha': () => ({name: 'beta'}),
    'beta': () => ({name: 'beta'}),
    'charlie': () => ({name: 'beta'}),
    'delta': () => ({name: 'beta'}),
}
```

But the issue here is that all records are content to *any* MyKey (`beta` in this case) as the `name` value. I want to constrain it to

```
const example: MyRecords = {
    'alpha': () => ({name: 'alpha'}),
    'beta': () => ({name: 'beta'}),
    'charlie': () => ({name: 'charlie'}),
    'delta': () => ({name: 'delta'}),
}
```

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiDSERQLxQOQEMA2YAWm6UAPhgEYTCEkYDGBATtgJYRGnoAmE2V6AsAChQkWCABKEWgHsGnAM6ookmXIA8cRCAA0UABQBKVAD4oAbwB2mALYQAXGK0BfY0KEyL84FAgAPG2DY9mIqsgpKZkJQ0Rg4%20IQOhib6ljbB6BR8TgbaUTEZlAn6Riimeqm2DgVZOXnR6PSYTKzoiSVlFemZhNm5gjEY3LxFSaUpVpXkhei9Qk5AA)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want to use [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) here at all, as it does not represent a relationship between the specific key types and value types.  If you use `Record<K, V>`, all properties will be of the same type.

Instead you should just write your own [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) where you refer to the key type parameter inside the property type.  Like this:

```
type MyRecords = { [K in MyKey]: () => { name: K } }
/* type MyRecords = {
    alpha: () => {
        name: "alpha";
    };
    beta: () => {
        name: "beta";
    };
    charlie: () => {
        name: "charlie";
    };
    delta: () => {
        name: "delta";
    };
} */
```

That's the type you want, and it behaves how you want with your example:

```
const example: MyRecords = {
    'alpha': () => ({ name: 'beta' }), // error
    'beta': () => ({ name: 'beta' }), // okay
    'charlie': () => ({ name: 'beta' }), // error
    'delta': () => ({ name: 'beta' }), // error
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiDSERQLxQOQEMA2YAWm6UAPhgEYTCEkYDGBATtgJYRGnoAmE2V6AsACghoSLBAAlCLQD2DTgGdUUAN5QA2vCjMAduMQgAugC4oACgCUqAHyqoOzAFsIprQF8oboQHoAVFFFoOClZeSU0FSEoaKgcfExTSxtVKJi0h2dTACI4giyAblTot0LBNIoqRKsUW0iytJiMlygsiswCos9StPpMJlYq5LqGxqdmrN7+iA764u6Y7l4E82razvSx7MWqGbSSoQ9fbyEhWR0FYCgIAA8nMGxm4Ok5RWVhmKxcAnRBmvM1JqmdBtIhuCwAGig3m8VwYDDknWBlEIv1sZgBm3IyNBEKhMJkAGtMCBEZMWGxUf97JikXxPLjobD4QxEdsUStkujqZksXSwZDGRA4QjBG4gA)